# nnet gives error Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, data-science, nnet

I am trying to run a nnet script in R :

> > ann <- nnet(Label ~ ., data=normed[Train_w_catDS,-1],
> >     weights=data.weights[Train_w_catDS], size=h, decay=5e-4, maxit
>
> =200)

where normed is

> normed <- cbind(data_w_catDS[,1:2],
>   as.data.frame(lapply(data_w_catDS[,-c(1,2)], function(col) { col /
>   max(abs(col)) })))

But I keep getting the error:

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

After multiple days of effort, i haven't been able to solve it.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the error coming in the calculation of `normed` or in the `nnet` call?

Comment: the error coming in the nnet call